# Extracting from File using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a text document that I would like to extract certain phrases from. The phrase is "MmarC5_" followed by 4 numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    re = (MmarC5_)
    re.findall(MmarC5_\d{4}", f.read())
```

I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'MmarC5' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the quotes:

```
re.findall(r"MmarC5_\d{4}", f.read())
```

And this line doesn't make any sense, delete it:

```
re = (MmarC5_)
```

Did you import the `re` module?

```
import re
```

Comment: Not only does it not make sense, it would make `re.findall` inaccessible, since `re` would be a reference to whatever `MmarC5_` was a reference to (assuming it was defined), instead of a reference to the module containing the `findall` function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to specify r for regex and enclose the regex expression in single quotes, so it should look like...

```
    re.findall(r'MmarC5_\d{4}', f.read())
```

Comment: `r` means "raw string", not "regex", although it is certainly suitable here.